# How to identify dataGridView cell that was right clicked on for ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, contextmenustrip

User right clicks on a cell within a DGV, then makes a selection in the ContextMenuStrip.  Based on their CMS selection, I want to do something (copy, hide, filter).  My problem is identifying the cell that was right clicked on.

I was trying to handle this scenario with the following method, but [ColumnIndex] cannot be referenced.

```
private void cmsDataGridView_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)
        {
            case "Copy":
                break;
            case "Filter On":
                break;
            case "Hide Column":
                DataGridViewBand band = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
                band.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Should I be doing this in two different methods?  One to handle the mouse click (in which I could then capture the DGV column index), then from within there, I call the CMS item clicked event?

Thank you for your help,
Brian.

---

The code that works for me.  Oh and I did have to remove the cmsDataGridView method from the ContextMenuStrip property of the dataGridView within the designer.  Leaving that in there caused problems.

```
            // Identify the cell clicked for cmsDataGridView
    DataGridViewCell clickedCell;
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                clickedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
                clickedCell.Selected = true;
                cmsDataGridView.Show(dataGridView1, e.Location);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void cmsDataGridView_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ClickedItem.Text)
        {
            case "Copy":
                break;
            case "Filter On":
                break;
            case "Hide Column":
                DataGridViewBand band = dataGridView1.Columns[clickedCell.ColumnIndex];
                band.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keep track of whichever cell was last clicked by adding an event handler for the DataGridView's mouse click.

Something like:

```
    DataGridViewCell clickedCell;

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
        try
    {
        DataGridView view = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clicked column " 
                       + e.ColumnIndex + ", row " 
                       + e.RowIndex + " of DataGridView " 
                       + view.Name + " at " 
                       + System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);

           clickedCell = view.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Then in your contextMenuStripItem click event, switch on clickedCell.Value like:

```
switch (clickedCell.Value)
        {
            case "Copy":
            break;
... // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'll modify my question with the answer that was a variation of Gojiria's.  I started with the mouseClick event that Seige suggested, but I did want to contain my code to the DGV only.  Thank you both.  Unfortunately, my status is too low to give either of you a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a HitTest with the datagridview.

This is an example of code that I have used.

```
        DataGridView dgv= (DataGridView)sender;
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            try
            {
                dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[gvw.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex, dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex];
            }
        }
```

You can then use the DGV.CurrentCell to find all the information.

```
switch ""
{
    case ""
      break;
}
```